# Same Bundle Id to be used in other account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, itunes-app

**Problem** - I have an app and I am using push notification. It's developed completely and is being tested using test flight. Now I want to use the same Bundle Id in other account so that I don't have problem with push notification or where ever I have used bundle id.

1. What if I delete the previous account app and then use it in new iTunes account?
2. Is there any solution?
3. Can be be tranfered before submission?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create Apps on App Store with same bundle ID.

Other wise I guess, you have to for transfer the app from one account to another account
[Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

1. What if I delete the previous account app and then use it in new iTunes account? - **Go for Transferring app**
2. Is there any solution? - **YES, as mentioned above.** or **Create new one bundle id**
3. Can be be transferred before submission? - **Not sure, but transferring keeps all data same, rating , reviews and all.**